# OrientDB: Find all vertices that have no direct neighbour vertex of a given class

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

Using OrientDB's query language, how can find all vertices in cluster `a` that have no outgoing edge ending in a vertex of class `b` (i.e. no direct neighbour vertex of class `b`)?
It does not matter if they have other outgoing edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've a class A mapped to cluster a you can do:

```
select from A where not( out.in.@class in ['b'] )
```

That means cross the "out" property of A records (as edges), then the "in" property (the vertex) and then get the class name (@class). I've used the IN operator instead of = (equals) because "out.in.@class" returns a collection of class names.

If you want have no A class and you have to go through the cluster A use cluster: syntax:

```
 select from cluster:A where not( out.in.@class in ['b'] )
```

I've tested against latest 1.0rc8-SNAPSHOT and works.

Comment: Is that really the syntax? There is no difference between the two cases. I cannot get it to work (on rc7). I get `unknown function "not"`. Does the double quote at the end need to be matched?

Comment: Works only with 1.0rc8-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Okay, will check after it's released. Any way to do it with an earlier version? And what is the meaning of the double quote at the end?

Comment: Sorry for " it comes from cut & paste. With previous release there is no way to do it in one shot unless you use GREMLIN function (use the Graph(ed) distribution) like "SELECT FROM GREMLIN(<expression>) FROM A". More on gremlin expressions: https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki

Comment: Okay, last question, then you get your +1 ;-) : What is the difference between the cluster-syntax query and the first one? They look exactly the same?

Comment: Class is a higher level concept than cluster (http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/Concepts#Cluster) taken from Object Orientation. When you create a class you can define in what cluster(s) record will go. By default there is 1 cluster per class with the same name, so in your case it's pretty the same. But you could create a class Employee that stores record on employee2011 and employee2012 clusters. This allow to query all the employee using the class or filter by year using the cluster.

Comment: You could also filter per year using a filter in SQL select if you declare a "year" field (select from employee where year = 2012), but this is much more efficient because avoid scanning of all the clusters but just the right one. The combination Class/Cluster is very powerful and allows to resolve many use cases.

Comment: I've create this section in WiKi: http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/Concepts#Class. Hope it helps.

Comment: so the second query in your answer should have been `select from cluster:a where not( out.in.@class in ['b'] )`?

Comment: Yes, fixed in the answer above